# How to find riesz measure of a function?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

How to find the Riesz measure for some given subharmonic function? For example,
let $u(z)=u(Re(z))$ be a continuous piecewise linear function, what is it's riesz measure? My teacher says that it has form $\mu(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\delta(x-x_n)dy$, where $x_n$ are endpoints, but I can't figure out why is it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be true. There are constants missing in the sum. First consider a (continuous) piecewise linear function on $\mathbb{R}$ and compute the second order distributional derivative. For example, take $f(x) = |x|$. Then $f'(x) = 2\theta(x)-1$ and $f''(x) = 2\delta(x)$ (in the distributional sense). Here $\theta$ is the Heaviside function.

Similarly, if $f$ is continuous and piecewise linear, then $f'' = \sum c_n\delta(x-x_n)$ for suitable contants $c_n$. (More precisely, $c_n = f'_+(x_n)-f'_-(x_n)$ is the change of the derivatives as we cross a "corner" in the graph of $f$.)

Hence, in two dimensions, if $u(x,y) = f(x)$, where $f$ is piecewise linear, then
$$
\mu_u = \Delta u =  \sum c_n\delta(x-x_n)\,dy.
$$

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed that in OP. I didn't think that we can find $\delta$ of such function.

Comment: One more thing: why $\mu_u=\Delta u$, where can I read about it?

Comment: @aptypr For example, section 4.3 of *Classical Potential Theory* by
  David H. Armitage, Stephen J. Gardiner. [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=02p9FQ41o9cC).

Comment: @aptypr Also, you can work directly from the definition of Riesz measure, and show that the measure $\mu$ in the answer satisfies $\int u\Delta \phi=\int \mu \phi$ for any test function $\phi$. The starting point is to split $\int u\Delta \phi$ into integrals over vertical strips on which $u$ is harmonic, and integrate by parts in each strip. This produces boundary terms which add up to $\int \mu \phi$. The answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/372595/) have something similar going on.